# Extracting Ecto fragment into variable

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a fragment, which is repetitive and quite complex. I would like to extract it into variable/function and reuse it multiple times instead of writing it more than once. Here's one simplified example what I tried so far among with many different approaches:

```
f = dynamic([u], fragment("order by name desc"))
query = from(u in User)
        |> order_by([u], ^f)
Repo.all(query)
```

According to [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2) it should be possible by using `dynamic`, but however I try within `order_by`, `select`, `having` or whatsoever I get an error message similar to:

```
(ArgumentError) expected a field as an atom, a list or keyword list in `order_by`, got: `dynamic([u], fragment("order by name desc"))`
```

How would I achieve it?

---

Update 1

Here's more real-life example. The following code works:

```
    from(p in Photo,
      join: pv in assoc(p, :v),
      left_join: pl in assoc(p, :l),
      left_join: pc in assoc(p, :c),
      select: %{p | last_activity_at: fragment("greatest(?, ?, ?)", max(p.inserted_at), max(pl.inserted_at), max(pc.inserted_at))},
      group_by: p.id,
      order_by: [desc: fragment("greatest(?, ?, ?)", max(p.inserted_at), max(pl.inserted_at), max(pc.inserted_at))]
    )
```

However, I cannot get it to work by extracting fragment out or using it with dynamic or whatever.

Comment: Can you try `|> order_by(f)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example for `order_by` in the very same documentation for [`Ecto.Query.dynamic/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2-order_by)

```rb
f = dynamic([u], fragment("order by name desc"))
# order_by = [desc: :name] # why not just this?
order_by = [desc: ^f]
query = from(u in User), order_by: ^order_by
Repo.all(query)
```

---

For the updated example:

```rb
order = dynamic(
  [p, pl, pc], 
  fragment(
    "greatest(?, ?, ?)",
    max(p.inserted_at),
    max(pl.inserted_at),
    max(pc.inserted_at)
  )
)

from(
  p in Photo,
  join: pv in assoc(p, :v),
  left_join: pl in assoc(p, :l),
  left_join: pc in assoc(p, :c),
  select: ...,
  group_by: p.id,
  order_by: ^[desc: order]
)
```

As it is stated in the documentation,

> it is not possible to pass dynamics outside of a root. For example, this won't work:
>
> ```
>  from query, order_by: [asc: ^dynamic(...)]
> ```
>
> But this will:
>
> ```
> from query, order_by: ^[asc: dynamic(...)]
> ```

Comment: `desc: :name` was a simplified example. See my updated question of a more real-life example, which I still cannot make work. And yes, I'm aware of the documentation examples, and this is how I tried as well as you proposed, but same error. Can it be that Ecto (or Ecto.Sql) versions matter?

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your changes.

Comment: I found that I was not able to use this syntax due to older ecto_sql (3.1.6). Upgrading it to 3.4.2 allowed me to use this syntax. However, I ditched using it since I also needed to use it in `select: %{p | max_date: greatest...}` however, was not able to. Also, I have some `having` statements. Anyway, seems great, but too hard to make it work normally.